# Gradle sync failed in android studio 1.4.1

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

Gradle sync error. Daemon process unable to start because it cannot reserve enough space in the heap.Please assign more memory in the heap.

I tried adding this "org.gradle.jvmargs=XX:MaxHeapSize\=256m-Xmx256m" in the gradle.properties file. Tried changing configuration settings. Nothing seems to work. Can anyone please help me with this?
Can you also explain the concept of gradle? I have tried read about it, nothing seems to expain.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see "Gradle VM options".

[image]

or from the command line,

```
export GRADLE_OPTS="
-server
-Xms2g
-Xmx2g
-XX:NewSize=512m
-XX:MaxNewSize=512m
-XX:+UseParNewGC
-XX:ParallelGCThreads=4
-XX:MaxTenuringThreshold=1
-XX:SurvivorRatio=8
-XX:+UseCodeCacheFlushing
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
-XX:+AggressiveOpts
-XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled
-XX:+CMSParallelRemarkEnabled
-XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=65
-XX:+CMSScavengeBeforeRemark
-XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=64m
-XX:-TraceClassUnloading
-ea
-Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false"
```